# Problema al crear Wifi hotspot

Tags: dns

Estoy creando un servidor DNS en una laptop sin tener que instalar windows server u otro SO tipo server. Encontré que existe este programa "Unbound" que es un servidor DNS ligero. El programa requería una configuración para que funcionase y ya lo configuré. Luego de esto probé el programa y correctamente funciona perfectamente cuando hago consultas desde otra PC pero mediante la LAN. Mi objetivo es crear con la laptop un punto de acceso y utilizar el servidor DNS para resolver las peticiones de los diferentes dispositivos que se conecten. Instalé el connectify y compartiendo la Ethernet en el connectify Unboud resuelve las peticiones pero esto solo funciona cuando la laptop está conectada a una LAN si no no funciona. Es decir la laptop sola sin cables de red con el connectify creando hotspot no resuelve las peticiones y la laptop conectada mediante LAN y connectify creando hotspot si resuelve las peticiones. ¿Como puedo resolver este problema?
Gracias.

Comment: El problema que creo que tienes es que esperas poder usar la conexión inalámbrica para conectar el portátil y compartir la conexión de forma simultánea. Sólo si tu interfaz tuviese múltiples antenas podrías hacer eso. Tu equipo va a usar siempre una interfaz sólo para conectarse y otra para compartir las conexiones

Comment: A ver. Tal vez expliqué mal la situación. Cunado digo LAN me refiero al adaptador ethernet. Mediante la wifi nunca me conecto, solo creo con el connectify. De igual manera los programas como el connectify permiten estar conectada la wifi y a la vez crear un hotspot.

Comment: Me he dado cuenta que cada vez que creo un hotspot windows crea un adaptador wifi virtual. No sé si eso interfiera con la configuración de Unboud que a lo mejor no admite adaptadores virtuales.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  no es una pregunta de programación.

Comment: ¿Y dónde puedo preguntar sobre este tema?

Comment: aquí hermano/a https://superuser.com/ es una página de la red de StackOverflow